# Documentation for Non Rest API Framework Project of Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I have a running Django project with custom views and URLs defined. But there are lot of of URL doing different type of stuff. How can i make a nice documentation for them, similar to rest API framework of Django. Django REST Swagger is one of the best framework available for generating documentation of rest frameworks. What Framework or template i can use for documentation of Django  projects that are not built using rest framework.

Comment: could you find a solution for non-rest framework django documentation?

Comment: Unfortunately i could not find any help.